# Java - jsoup get element with specific string

Tags: java, jsoup, element

I would like to select an element that matches a specific String

```
<img src='http://iblink.ch/resized/sjg63ngi3h3g4a.jpg' alt='tree'>
```

since I don't have a specific class or div to trigger I try to use `getElementsContainingOwnText("resized")`

method to get this element.
But it does not find it?
I also try: [getElementsContainingText](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsContainingText-java.lang.String-)
Same output :(

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Its says  element's text not its attribute (here `src`'s) text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is the part outside the tags: `<tag attribute="value">Text</tag>`

So you want to select Elements with a certain attribute value like this:

```
Elements els = doc.select("img[src*=resized]");
```

Have a look into [CSS selectors as they are implemented in Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked!